# Spring MVC <mvc:resources> mappings is not affecting url

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm just wondering if anyone has encountered an issue where the url you enter to get a static file takes the location string instead of mapping string?
e.g.

> location="/resources/" mapping="/myResources/**"

1) url: http://localhost:8080/MVCdemo/myReources/img.png

2) url: http://localhost:8080/MVCdemo/reources/img.png

url 2 will work but url 1 doesn't (404), even though that is what is mapped?

Comment: for anyone having the same problem, change url-pattern from *.html to / for the fix